# check if all input field has value jQuery condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have several input fields with a class name of `required`.

i have a code below to check if all my `<input>` fields have a value, if not empty or null, it will show/unhide a specific `div`.

but it doest seem to work on me.

also, by default, `#print` is displayed as none via CSS.

```
<!-- index.php -->

<input type="text" id="getID" class="required form-control" placeholder="id">
<input type="text" id="getName" class="required form-control" placeholder="name">

<!-- script.js -->

$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('input.required').each(function() { 
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        $("#print").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#print").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You haven't given the inputs any value and the validation is running on `$(document).load()`, you could try binding it to a `click` or a `submit` event instead

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#print').toggle(!($('input.required').length == $('input.required').filter(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).length));
```

[Simplified JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FdcAt/).

Obviously this should be run on `submit`, assuming you want to only show the `#print` element as a validation prior to submission.

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment above, you're checking the values when the page loads, before the user has any chance to enter anything. If you have a button on your page, bind the event to that which will fire the function at the right time.

Something a little like this [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/STbaG/1/)

**index.php**

```
<input type="text" id="getID" class="required form-control" placeholder="id">
<input type="text" id="getName" class="required form-control" placeholder="name">
<div id="button">Submit</div>
<div id="print">You're missing something D:!</div>
```

**script.js**

```
$('#button').on('click', function() { 
    $('#print').hide();
    var error=false;
    $('input.required').each(function() { 
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            error=true;
        }
    });
    if(error) {
        $('#print').show();   
    }
});
```

Comment: But the check is inside an each so the #print div will be visible according to the last input validation

Comment: Edited, noticed that the second I put it into a fiddle :P

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //the default state
    var valid = true;
    $('input.required').each(function () {
        //if the value of the current input is blank then the set is invalid and we can stop the iteration now
        if ($.trim(this.value) == '') {
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    //set the visibility of the element based on the value of valid state
    $("#print").toggle(!valid);
});
```